# insert new value to HTML list through javascript using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have to insert new value to HTML list for my automation purpose. I am using selenium with     python.

My list is:

```
<select name="sel_audio" id="sel_audio">
    <option value="endo/audio/beep.wav" selected="selected">beep </option>
    <option value="endo/audio/dig1.wav">dig1 </option>
    <option value="endo/audio/IMAlert.wav">IMAlert </option>
    <option value="endo/audio/IMAlertDef.wav">IMAlertDef </option>
</select>
```

I want ot add HighPiono.wav file to list. My code is:

```
self.script = "document.getElementById('sel_audio').value='" + C:\music\HighPiono.wav + "';"
driver.execute_script(self.script)
```

This code is setting the blank value  in list without giving any error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `add()` method of `Select` object to add new option to it. Below JavaScript will add new option to select list:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("sel_audio");
var new_option = document.createElement("option");
new_option.text = "HighPiono";
new_option.value = "HighPiono.wav";
sel.add(option);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Surya.                                                                 I am converting this code in python to run from selenium as follows:                                                               sel = self._browser.get_current_browser().execute_script("document.getElementById('sel_audio')")                                               new_option = self._browser.get_current_browser().execute_script("document.createElement('option')")                                                   new_option.text = "HighPiono" new_option.value = "HighPiono.wav" sel.add(option)

Comment: Then I am getting following error:                                                                 (<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'",), <traceback object at 0x00000000035FFC08>)

Comment: Why are you modifying like this? you have to just replace "self.script" with the JS script that I have provided in your code... Hope this helps!